# The react-google-charts timeline freezes the browser window when you have two data points, each lasting only one second

Tags: timeline, react-google-charts

I'm currently building a timeline chart and have data that changes partially every second. Through debugging, I eventually found out that the freezing happens when I have two consecutive data points, each lasting only one second. The freezing appears when Im changing the browser window size repeatly and with a little bit of speed.

Is there any way I can use the timeline chart from react-google-charts?

Im currently using the newest version 4.0.1.

See also https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mystifying-merkle-5xcwtz?file=%2FApp.tsx%3A3%2C1 and try it out yourself.